# node --debug-brk doesn't work

Tags: debugging, node.js

I think the `--debug-brk` CLI options makes `node` stop at first line of script.

But it doesn't.

```
$node --debug-brk app.js 

debugger listening on port 5858

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'port' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/raincole/nodejs_projects/app.js:35:76)
```

The line 35 of `app.js` still be executed. Why the `--debug-brk` doesn't work?

My `node` version is 0.6.10.

Comment: WFM on node 0.6.3 (Linux). Looks like you filed a bug with node directly. (https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2724 )
Generally, if you file a bug, I don't think it's necessary to also create an SO question.

Comment: Try adding this redundancy: `node --debug-brk debug app.js`